# C++ : cannot create node pointer inside ostream& operator <<

Tags: c++

I'm using C++ to implement LinkedList, other functions and operators I can create Node* just fine. However when I get to this operator **"ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const LinkedList& list)"** (output the list), I can not create a temporary inside the operator, can anyone tell me what causes the error and how to fix it?

Here is my LinkedList.h

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class LinkedList {
    typedef struct Node{
        int data;
        Node* next;

    bool operator < (const Node& node) const {
        return this->data < node.data;
    }

    bool operator <= (const Node& node) const {
        return this->data <= node.data;
    }

    bool operator > (const Node& node) const {
        return this->data > node.data;
    }

    bool operator >= (const Node& node) const {
        return this->data >= node.data;
     }

    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const LinkedList& list);
    friend istream& operator >> (istream& in, const LinkedList& list);

    } * nodePtr;

public: 
    nodePtr head;
    nodePtr curr;
    LinkedList();

   // functions
    void push_front(int);
    void push_back(int);
    int pop_front();
    int pop_back();
    int size();
    bool contains(int);
    void print();
    void clear();

   // overload
    LinkedList& operator =(const LinkedList& list);
    bool operator !=(const LinkedList& list) const;
    LinkedList operator +(const int v) const;
    LinkedList operator +(const LinkedList& list) const;
    LinkedList operator - (const int v) const;   
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const LinkedList& list);
    friend istream& operator >> (istream& in, const LinkedList& list);  
   };

 #endif /* LINKEDLIST_H */
```

in my LinkedList.cpp:

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const LinkedList& list) {
    nodePtr temp = list.head;          <----------------- **Unable to resolve identifier nodePtr**
}
```

I can create Node* (nodePtr) on my other functions just fine.

Comment: Your other functions are actually a part of `LinkedList`. This one isn't. The name lookup rules change for the same reason you wouldn't want `main` to be able to do `nodePtr temp` and have it find your class.

Comment: what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nodePtr` is defined inside `LinkedList`, it need to be qualified. Change

```
nodePtr temp = list.head;
```

to

```
LinkedList::nodePtr temp = list.head;
```